# How do I actually use RDS CALs?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, cal

I'm new to CALs, first time actually trying to use them, and I'm having some difficulties. I purchased 3 licences from CDW and installed them through the RD Licensing manager, where they show up as:

- License version and type: Windows Server 2012 - Installed RDS Per
  Device CAL
- License Program: Open
- Total Licenses: 3
- Issued: 0

So I believe I have them installed correctly. The "Remote Desktop Services" and "Remote Access" roles are currently enabled in the Server Manager.

How do I actually get the server to issue a license to a desktop? The way I understand it so far is the machine remote desktops into the server and is first issued a temporary key, and the second time the machine logs into the server a purchased key is assigned to that machine. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the licenses are assigned as they log in. There is no way to affix a license to a specific device, and definitely not beforehand.

Comment: So all the user has to do is log into the computer twice from theirs using Remote Desktop, provided their account has permission to use remote desktop to the server?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Should be the last question - these CALs can still be issued during the 120 day grace period, correct?

Comment: They will be issued. The 120 day grace period is just when enforcement begins. Note that during that 120 day grace period, the server is still counting logins. If you log in with a more devices than you have licenses, then when the grace period expires only 3 devices will have licenses, and it might not be the 3 that you want. So don't go too crazy.